# How many times can I multiple a number by a decimal/fraction before it reaches close to zero

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, math, game-engine, game-physics

I'm trying to determine how far ahead to check for a ledge based on an objects speed. This way the object can stop accelerating and let friction stop it.

[image]

**the problem**

friction is 0.9 * horizontalSpeed each step.

when horizontalSpeed is less than 0.001 we set the horizontalSpeed to 0

how long it takes to reach 0.001 is horizontalSpeed = 1

**how im currently solving**

```js
var horizontalSpeed = 1    
var friction = 0.9
var closeEnoughToZero = 0.001
var distance = 0

while(horizontalSpeed > closeEnoughToZero) {
    horizontalSpeed *= friction
    distance += horizontalSpeed
}

console.log(distance) // 8.99
```

Possible already the solution I just feel it is a bit brute force and likely some type of math function that is handy for this!

Comment: using maths of geometric progressions, the formula would be `(horizontalSpeed * friction)/(1-friction)` - now, this should be exactly 9, but due to floating point arithmetic, it unfortunately results in ` 9.000000000000002`

Comment: Did not check, but seems like [Harmonic Progression](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_progression_(mathematics))

Comment: yippie that worked! :]

Comment: which one worked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a "pure maths" solution

```js
var horizontalSpeed = 1    
var friction = 0.9
var closeEnoughToZero = 0.001
var distance = (horizontalSpeed * friction)/(1-friction)

console.log(distance)
```

Or, given a "close enough to zero", that can be done without a loop too

```js
var horizontalSpeed = 1    
var friction = 0.9
var closeEnoughToZero = 0.001
var distance = 0

// this is the power you need to raise "friction" to, to get closeEnoughToZero
let n = Math.ceil(Math.log(closeEnoughToZero)/Math.log(friction)); 
// now use the formula for Sum of the first n terms of a geometric series
let totalDistance = horizontalSpeed * friction * (1 - Math.pow(friction, n))/(1-friction);
console.log(totalDistance);
```

I use the `Math.ceil` of `Math.log(closeEnoughToZero)/Math.log(friction)` - which in your case is 66. If you added a loop counter to your code, you'd see the loop executes 66 times

And, as you can see the second code produces exactly the same output as your loop.